# How to repeat testng suite-files with different parameters

Tags: testng

My requirement is that I have to repeat a suite (SBSuite.xml) which has multiple tests, with different set of parameters. I tried the below configuration but getting error. Can we repeat the suite-file or what is the correct solution to repeat a single suite file multiple times with params ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="SBCrossBrowser">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="net.sf.testng.databinding.TestAnnotationTransformer"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <suite-files>
        <parameter name="browser" value="CHROME" />
        <suite-file path="SBSuite.xml"/>
    </suite-files>


    <suite-files>
        <parameter name="browser" value="IE" />
        <suite-file path="SBSuite.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

I am getting following error :

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Two suites cannot have the same name: SBSuite
    at org.testng.TestNG.checkSuiteNamesInternal(TestNG.java:1019)
    at org.testng.TestNG.checkSuiteNamesInternal(TestNG.java:1022)
    at org.testng.TestNG.checkSuiteNames(TestNG.java:1012)
    at org.testng.TestNG.sanityCheck(TestNG.java:985)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: Which TestNG version do you use? Could you try with the latest version?

Comment: The issue is already known: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/951

Comment: thanks @juherr, looks like the only solution is the duplicate the suite into something link ChromeSuite.xml, FFSuite.xml and run from master suite.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you `have to repeat a suite (SBSuite.xml) which has multiple tests, with different set of parameters` IMO it would be better to put the entire testing steps under `Test` Annotation. Create single Test Suite to be executed with different set of parameters through `<parameter>` tag. e.g. `<parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>`

Remember to keep the name of the Test Suites different. Through this approach you can execute the TestSuites one after another as well as parallel.

Let me know if this solves your Question.

Comment: I think you are suggesting to create different <Test> nodes for different browsers. This will work but will not solve my need. My need is that I have around 20 <Test>'s which I don't want to put together into single Test. And secondly, I don't want to replicate the same Suite with different parameters (ex FireFoxSuite.xml, IESuite.xml) to run on different browsers. So I followed the method I mentioned in the question. But it is throwing  error.